# What should this javascript query actually look like?

Tags: javascript, ssrs-2008

I am a beginner at this.I am trying to write an expression that will make an image  act as a hyperlink to another report.

```
="javascript:IP.Reporting.OpenSSRSModal(""/PremiumAndRevenueAnalysis/BSDBranch/BSDBranch/Reports/RenewalPipelinePoliciesPopUp.rdl"",{" & """Location"":[""" & REPLACE(JOIN(Parameters!BUHierarchyName.Value,","),"&","%2526") & """],""SegmentFilter"":1,""SegmentName"":[""" & REPLACE(Fields!Segment.Value,"&","%2526") & """]});"
```

---

I am getting an error :  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.`

Could someone please help me identify the problem?

Comment: Is this in from HTML, like `<img onClick="javascript:blahblah"/>` or something else. It looks like the quotes are being escaped in an odd way that would make HTML blow-up.

Comment: Yes! I tried different ways but doesnt seem to work right.